# Python 2.7 literal_eval() with a UTF-8 string

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8, eval, unicode-string

I'm updating an older application for Python 3, but trying to maintain compatibility if possible with Python 2.7.  One of the issues I've encountered deals with inconsistencies in `ast.literal_eval()` between Python 2 & 3, when handling a UTF-8 string.

Specifically, one of the functions my application performs involves:

1. Reading a string from a UTF-8 encoded text file that represents a Python list of file names
2. Converting that UTF-8 string to a Python list via `literal_eval()`
3. Using that list to access those files and perform other processing.

My test .txt file has this string:

> ['FileName1.txt', 'CP1252-1-àlacrème.txt', 'dUTF8-1-木兰辞.txt']

I'm using this brief test script to emulate what the larger application does:

```
import io
from ast import literal_eval

with io.open('z.txt','r',encoding='utf_8') as inFile:
    inStr = inFile.read()
print('Input string is length '+str(len(inStr)))

fileList = literal_eval(inStr)
print(fileList)
```

Now, when I run this test script on Python 3, I get the following (all OK and as expected) result:

> Input string is length 61
>
> ['FileName1.txt', 'CP1252-1-àlacrème.txt','dUTF8-1-???.txt']

*(The question marks are expected as this is a Windows CMD window; it doesn't handle non-latin-1 characters)*

But anyway, when I run the same script with the same file on Python 2.7, I get this result:

> Input string is length 61
>
> ['FileName1.txt', 'CP1252-1-\xc3\xa0lacr\xc3\xa8me.txt', 'dUTF8-1-\xe6\x9c\xa8\xe5\x85\xb0\xe8\xbe\x9e.txt']

So `literal_eval()` isn't maintaining the UTF-8 encoding in the resulting list.  (Or, I guess, it's **trying** to maintain the encoding but the best it can do is represent the non-ASCII data as individual byte values.)

My question is:  is there any way to make the Python 2 `literal_eval()` give the same result as the Python 3 version?  Or am I stuck with this as a limitation?

Comment: Is it just a problem of 'print' ?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, no, it affects any usage of those list elements -- writing the list back out to a file, using the elements to open the referenced files, etc.

Comment: What about parsing all `literal_eval` elements and converting the string to unicode? As you see on result, the string are seen as string (not unicode) on Python2.7 (no `u` prefix)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, looks like that's a step closer.  Instead of just the `literal_eval()` I used this list comprehension:  `[codecs.decode(fn,'utf_8') for fn in literal_eval(inStr)]`   It gives the desired result for Python 2.  But now Python 3 rejects it with a `TypeError` exception (because the input is a string rather than a bytes-like object).  Perhaps I'll just have to settle for a `try-except` structure, putting the Python-2 version as the try and the Python 3 version as the except.

Comment: This code would also work differently if UTF-8 were not the default codec, such as on Windows.  On Python 2, `ast.literal_eval` will parse `'àlacrème'` as a byte string, using a different default encoding, wheras on Python 3 it will parse as a Unicode string.  The problem is writing Python source syntax to a text file.  Write it as a CSV file with a specific encoding instead.  Python 2 and 3 have different syntax so `ast.literal_eval` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, will the `csv` modules of 2.7 & 3.x generate consistent results if I go that direction?  If so, this sounds like a good solution.

Comment: The `csv` modules between 2 and 3 have different syntax for use, and the Python 2 version doesn't handle UTF-8 well.  `pandas` works better.  I'll provide an answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `ast.literal_eval` of the input parses differently between Python 2 and 3.  Better to not write Python source as a data file, but use a module like `pandas` with .csv files:

If the input is a UTF-8 file with content:

```
FileName1.txt,CP1252-1-àlacrème.txt,dUTF8-1-木兰辞.txt
```

Then `pandas` can read it with:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.txt',encoding='utf8',header=None)
print(data)
```

Output (Windows terminal Python 3, need appropriate font):

```
               0                      1                2
0  FileName1.txt  CP1252-1-àlacrème.txt  dUTF8-1-木兰辞.txt
```

Output (Windows IDLE, Python 2 in console needs appropriate code page to view ideographs):

```
               0                      1                2
0  FileName1.txt  CP1252-1-àlacrème.txt  dUTF8-1-木兰辞.txt
```

Comment: Put together a test script and it's working on 3.x as well as 2.7.  Thanks!